# how to get value from list view on its double click event(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem guys i want to get the row detail when i click that row on my listview i know it how it perform in window form but it is different in WPF /i m using C# wpf please help me out 
thanks in Advance
shashank

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the ListView, you can use the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property.  You could also bind SelectedItem to a property on your ViewModel and then read the value from there.  Finally, you could set [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) to True on your ListView and then use:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(sourceList).CurrentItem
```

where sourceList is the ItemsSource of the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event handler to your ListViewItems by adding the following XAML to your `<Window.Resources>`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="MyEventHandler" />
</Style>
```

Then you must add an event handler in your code:

```
 private void MyEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem MyListViewItem = (ListViewItem)sender;
        MyClass MyObject = (MyClass)Item.Content;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

In this example, `MyObject` contains the object that is bound to the ListViewItem that was clicked on. For example, in one of my projects, I have a ListView that is bound to an `ObservableCollection<SongData>`. I would then use the following code:

```
  private void MyEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem Item = (ListViewItem)sender;
        SongData Song = (SongData)Item.Content;

        // Example
        MessageBox.Show(Song.Title + " by " + Song.Artist);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I don't know if this gets you any further, but it should work fine.

Oh, and by the way, you could also attach an eventhandler to the `ListView` use the `SelectedItem` property, but for me that resulted in some problems, for example, if you click on a columnheader or a blank space while an item is selected, it also triggers the eventhandler. Therefore, I'd rather use my first proposed approach.

Comment: man u deserves a vote up
This help me:
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem Item = (ListViewItem)sender;
        SongData Song = (SongData)Item.Content;

        // Example
        MessageBox.Show(Song.Title + " by " + Song.Artist);

        e.Handled = true;
    }

Comment: Actually I'm a Java/Android developer have vast knowledge in Java/Android but working on sister's project which has to be in .net so i was working on wpf xaml based application and I'm new to C# wpf..

this really help me